# Should I be creating Like Box and Like Buttons for others while logged into my Facebook account?

Tags: facebook-like

Lately, I have been getting a lot of requests for Like buttons and Like boxes for clients. I generally create the quick plugins while being logged into my own Facebook; in fact, you can't access those areas without being logged into Facebook.

I have a few web applications created for my personal websites: are these new plugins I create for other people now somehow associated with my account? I see an application ID in one of the boxes...there's got to be a cleaner way to do this without having to ask for someone's Facebook login to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This page will create a like button for someone based on a URL, no need to be in a facebook account:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/